# Check if a certain link from a certain user exists and retrieve additional data

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to find if a certain Facebook user 
**shared** a link in his/her wall 
and get details about that post?

Details: Time posted, likes, comments?

For example : https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=URL&user=FBid

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can see the links that the user has shared by calling `http:graph.facebook.com/me/links?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN`   See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ for more information about the `links` connection on the `user` object.